# how to select multiple column name dynamically In SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How to Select a Column's Value Dynamically from a Table, where columns are not fixed?

I have a table name **EMP** which contains a **numbers of dynamic columns**.

```
id     Items    Col1      Col2   Col3   Col4  ... .... ... Col20   -----> Columns 

 1       ABC    20         40    100    32    ..  ..  .    200     -----> Values
```

Now I have a Dynamic Formula like

**Round(Col1+Col4+Col20,2)+100**

For Solving this formula I have to fetch the particular columns's value, which are associated to that columns and finally execute the query according to the formula.

I can Apply 2 methods

```
                                    First Method
```

select col1,col4,col20 from EMP

but it will not work because I do not know the columns's name, even I get extract the required columns form the formula, but after getting the columns name. how can i select them dynamically from the EMP table?

```
                            ****Second Method****
```

declare @holder int,@holder2 int.....

SELECT @holder=col1,@holder=col2..... FROM emp

It will also not work, because how can I Declare the a numbers of Dynamic variable for every column?

How can I do it?
Please Help

Comment: you can check if a colum name exists and then execute it

Comment: SQL Server does not support macro substitution nor does it have an EVAL() function.  This leaves Dynamic SQL

Comment: SQL, the language itself, doesn't allow arbitrary column names. Tables and columns in SQL are equivalent to types in a strongly typed language. When a query gets executed it's compiled into an execution plan based on the tables, columns, indexes and the data statistics. Different columns would result in *completely* different execution plans

Comment: What does `contains a numbers of dynamic columns.` mean? There's no such feature. You can have *sparse* columns but those are still defined in advance. All 30000 of them. `I have a Dynamic Formula like 'Round(Col1+Col4+Col20,2)+100'` why not include that in a SELECT statement then?

Comment: Dear @PanagiotisKanavos, actually as per the requirement, Columns and its values are defined from the front-end dynamically , so columns are not fixed ..... another thing I have to perform a required transaction according to the formula which are defined in the same table name Formula_Defined

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should only use Dynamic SQL for this purpose.
like this :

```
declare @columns varchar(max) = 'Col1 , Col2 , Col3' ;    
declare @sql varchar(mx) = 'SELECT '+ @columns +'FROM emp' ;
```

Comment: Dear @shahriar , From this code I will get only the tables columns and its value, but I also want the final execution/calculation as per the formula define...

Comment: @dhirendra-joshi , I know . you can put your formula in the varchar variable and concat it with the rest of query: EXEC 'SELECT '+ formula +' FROM emp ' . while formula  is set to 'Round(Col1+Col4+Col20,2)+100' .

Answer (score 0):

This is a very dubious requirement. Tables shouldn't have dynamic columns.

You can do something horrible with XML though ([DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5b2a7880ba19c155120542d174ebd377))

The below will dynamically find all columns in the table whose name starts with the prefix "Col" and then cast the contents to decimal and sum them.

```
SELECT t.*, (SELECT t.* FOR XML PATH('x'), TYPE).value('  
       let $sum := sum(
           for $col in x/*  
           where substring(local-name($col), 1, 3) eq "Col"
           return ($col cast as xs:decimal ?) 
       )
       return $sum', 
   'decimal(20,10)') AS Sum
 FROM YourTable t
```

Comment: Tables *don't* have dynamic columns. Even if the OP means sparse columns, they're already defined

Comment: Clearly they are meaning dynamic to mean "variable" and may differ at run time from when they are writing the query. It is indeed not a feature of a table but presumably indicative of some other code that alters the schema.

Comment: I wish the one who is going to have to give support on this query very muck luck! (and wisdom).  Especially when the sum is also dynamic, and not based on all column values.... (the way I interpret the question)

Comment: This sums all columns named with the prefix “Col”

Comment: That XQuery is overkill. The following is the same result `sum(for $c in x/*[substring(local-name(.), 1, 3) = "Col"]/text() return $c cast as xs:decimal?)` https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7f187695b2f1081718fb55e6d4926351

Comment: Alternatively don't bother casting `sum(x/*[substring(local-name(.), 1, 3) = "Col"]/text())` https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=28d330afd0c10123373f19fe503db3fc

Comment: @Charlieface - thanks. I only use the XML methods very rarely so not surprised there is a more concise way!

Answer (score 0):

Declare

```
@sql1       as nvarchar(MAX),
@para       as nvarchar(Max),-----'Holds all the columns name, that will extract from formula like col1,col2'
@formula    nvarchar(MAX),--- Holds the formula like Round(Col1+Col4+Col20,2)+100
@ABC        float,
```

set @sql1=N'

select * into datafetch from (
SELECT '+ @para+', '+@formula+' as  newcol'+' FROM Emp)abc'

exec(@sql1)

SELECT  @ABC=newcol FROM datafetch
---@ABC variable holds the final calculated value from the formula